# Unit testing button with routerLink directive

Tags: angular

I have a simple static view that I would like to write tests for:

```
<div class="landing-page">
 <app-cover>
   <app-stack [large]="true">
     <app-center> 
       <img src="assets/images/logo.svg" />
     </app-center>
     <app-center>
       <p>
         Try matching the employee to their photo.
       </p>
     </app-center>
     <app-center>
       <app-button routerLink="namegame">
         Play!
       </app-button>
     </app-center>
   </app-stack>
 </app-cover>
</div>
```

I was able to make assertions that the text of the `<p>` tag and the `<button>` are accurate easily. However, I am having trouble writing a unit test for the button behavior, e.g. when I click on the button I get navigated to the `/namegame` route.

The message I see from Karma is really confusing:

```
Chrome 83.0.4103.106 (Mac OS 10.15.5) NamegameComponent navigates to /namegame when the "Play" 

button is clicked FAILED
Expected spy navigateByUrl to have been called with:
 [ '/namegame', <jasmine.anything> ]
but actual calls were:
 [ /namegame, Object({ skipLocationChange: false, replaceUrl: false, state: undefined }) ].
Call 0:
 Expected $[0] = /namegame to equal '/namegame'.
```

Test code:

```
// ... imports ...

describe('NamegameComponent', () => {
 let component: LandingPageComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<LandingPageComponent>;
 let router: Router;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
     declarations: [
       LandingPageComponent,
       CenterComponent,
       CoverComponent,
       StackComponent,
       ButtonComponent,
     ],
   }).compileComponents();
 }));

 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LandingPageComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   router = TestBed.inject(Router);
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 // ... other tests ...

 it('navigates to /namegame when the "Play" button is clicked', () => {
   const navSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
   const button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('app-button');
   button.click();
   expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`/namegame`, jasmine.anything());
 });
});
```

Any ideas why the assertion doesn't match? Is there something wrong with the quoting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that [`navigateByUrl`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl) is called with a [`UrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) *not* a string like I expected initially.

Either one of these assertions will work:

```
// matching the UrlTree directly
expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  router.createUrlTree(['/namegame']), 
  jasmine.anything()
);
```

or

```
// explicitly convert the UrlTree to a string before comparison
expect(navSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0].toString()).toEqual('/namegame');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume it's because you are using backticks instead of normal quotes. Try:

```
expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/namegame', jasmine.anything());
```

Comment: unfortunately no, both single-quotes and double quotes-produce the same behavior.

Comment: can you try to change the template to `[routerLink]="'namegame'"`. It feels like there is some string issue, but never heard of it :)

Comment: That also produces the same behavior. It's super weird this is a stock app following the angular docs so I am not really sure what I have done wrong here.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen last option I can think of `[routerLink]="['namegame']"`, but if it works, it still doesn't explain why the previous options do not work

Comment: Nah unfortunately, that still produces the same message

Comment: the issue is`toHaveBeenCalledWith` is not correctly coercing the UrlTree to a string. This assertion works fine: `expect(navSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0].toString()).toEqual('/namegame');`

Comment: so does `expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/namegame'], jasmine.anything());`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen thanks for the update :) It makes sense in a way, looking at the source code. But it's good to know!